# Cannot compile GDB7.8 with Python support

Tags: python, gdb

I am trying to install GDB7.8 with Python support. From the source folder, I am running `./configure --with-python`
When I did tab-complete from --with- I did not see Python in the list. 
But when I ran configure with that flag, it did not baulk.

When I run make, it complains that Python is not found.

```
checking for python2.7... no
```

but Python is installed:

```
 $ which python
python                python2.7             python2.7-dbg-config
python2               python2.7-dbg 

$ which python2.7 
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

I compiled GDB without --with-python
and things installed without error. I was under the impression that GDB7.8 had Python support without the need for special flags. But when I run:

```
$gdb python
(gdb) run test.py
```

I get some sort of cannot import gdb Import error

So then I tried calling "pi":

```
(gdb) pi printf.py
Python scripting is not supported in this copy of GDB.
```

So... how do I get Python support in GDB7.8? is it actually not supported? Or should I not call "pi"?

Comment: Do `sh -x ./configure --with-python` and keep the output. Look for how `configure` handles `--with-*`, and look at the Makefile to see how it checks for `python2.7`. Could it need the `python2.7 source`?

Comment: Did you install the Python development files too? `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/devguide/gdb.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I spent quite a bit of time working on getting gdb (7.9) to work with Python (2.7). In the end everything worked rather well. However, there are a bunch of things that you have to get right. The key point is that the gdb configure script tries to compile a small C program that looks like this.

```
#include "Python.h"
int
main ()
{
Py_Initialize ();
  ;
  return 0;
}
```

If this program won't compile, then Python support won't be built. For this program to compile, the Python.h include file must be found in `/usr/include/python2.7`. This file will only exist if the `python-devel` package is installed. On my system (redhat), the command for installing this package is `sudo yum install python-devel`.

However, that's not enough to get Python installed. Before the configure script tries to compile the C program, it gets various options from `python-config.py`. If these options aren't correct, then the C program won't compile. On my system, `python-config.py` returned the options below.

```
-lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

These options didn't cause any problems in my environment. Other folks have had problems with the options returned from `python-config.py` and have made changes to `python-config.py` to resolve these problems. On my system the complete compile command was

```
gcc -o conftest -g -O2   -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 \
    conftest.c -ldl -lncurses -lz -lm -ldl    -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm \
    -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic
```

This compile command completed without any errors as soon as I installed `python-devel`. Note you don't have to manually enter the `gcc` command. I did run the `gcc` command several times to make sure everything was correct. Normally, the configure script will run the
compiler for you. Also note that to get the overall gdb install process to complete, `makeinfo` also had to be installed. The command for installing makeinfo was `sudo yum install texinfo`.

Overall, the correct set of steps seems to be

1. Install python-devel
2. Install texinfo
3. Download the gdb source and gunzip it and untar it.
4. `cd` to the `gdb-7.9` directory with the `configure` file.
5. ```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-python
   make 
   sudo make install
   ```

It should be possible to get gdb to work with Python 3. The various gdb scripts and install programs mention Python 3 in many, many places. However, the correct procedure for installing gdb with Python 3 is unknown to me at this point.

Answer (score 2):

With benefit of [Peter Schaeffer's excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/593746/1158700), I was able to build & install GDB 8.3.1 with Python 3.6, from source.  The critical insight was that the `LDFLAGS` and `LIBS` which `./configure` accepts *are different from* the `LDFLAGS` and `LIBS` which `make` requires.  Yes they should be same, but in this case they were not.

---

#### Pre-requisite Steps

1. install `python3` package
2. install `python3-devel` package
3. install `texinfo` package
4. run `/usr/bin/python3.6-config --includes`; that printed (twice!)

   ```
   -I/usr/include/python3.6m
   ```
5. run `/usr/bin/python3.6-config --ldflags`; that printed

   ```
   -L/usr/lib64 -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic
   ```
6. run `/usr/bin/python3.6-config --libs`; that printed

   ```
   -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
   ```
7. find the real path of "python3" binary, by running `readlink --canonicalize-existing $(which python3)`; that printed

   ```
   /usr/bin/python3.6
   ```

---

#### Build Steps

```bash
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/python3.6m"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64"
export LIBS="-lpython3"

readonly configureOptions="\
--disable-ada \
--disable-cloog-version-check \
--disable-gdbmi \
--disable-host-shared \
--disable-isl-version-check \
--disable-libssp \
--disable-libquadmath \
--disable-libquadmath-support \
--disable-objc-gc \
--disable-source-highlight \
--disable-stage1-checking \
--disable-static-libjava \
--disable-tui \
--disable-werror \
--enable-stage1-languages=c,c++ \
--enable-vtable-verify \
--with-python=/usr/bin/python3.6 \
--with-static-standard-libraries \
--with-system-zlib \
--without-cloog \
--without-guile \
--without-isl \
--without-mpfr \
"
./configure $configureOptions

export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic"
export LIBS="-lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm"

make

make install
```